# How to filter System generated mail in Java Using Exchange Web Service

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

> Hi I am using EWS api 1.2 for fethcing email headers from Exchange Outlook web service,WE need to filter mails that are system generated as this overheads our operation performance,is there any way to do this or is there any other Property of Exchange which is useful for filtering after fetching emails?

Comment: I don't know exchange too well so I'm not sure what you mean by "system generated". Did exchange generate them? Or is one of your systems sending out mails via exchange that you need to filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System Generated mails can be generated in almost all Exchange servers,for eg in outlook you can create certain rules and let system handle the incoming/outgoing mails baased on the conditions specified.

Same is with gmail,here we have canned replies.

Other examples are when a person goes in vacation,he/she can use the autoreply functionality present in different srvers to generate system gebnerated mails